# Conduct Knime Workflow using Web Input

Tags: python, web, knime

Does anyone have experience using inputs from a web-app into their Knime workflow? I'm thinking of using Python to somehow pull the .json or .csv that the website creates as input.. but I'm struggling on how to begin going about it.

Happy to provide further information to assist if possible.

Comment: There are reader nodes in KNIME for JSON or the File Reader will handle csv.  Both will take URLs or absolute file paths - that's probably easier than doing something with Python, unless you need to do something with the output first before KNIME gets hold of it, or in order to make it accessible to KNIME

Comment: Do the reader nodes in KNIME have some sort of event-listener that triggers whether the data is new?
This sounds like an on-demand only function.

Comment: Not directly, but there is a delay or wait node which can either was it for a file creation event or a period of time after which you could test if there was new data in a loop

Comment: Ok great.. thanks Steve. May have a few more questions in the near future. You've been a big help so far!

Comment: Glad to help (I wrote the original wait nodes in a community contribution, KNIME added the file event option when we donated it to them!)

Comment: Hey Steve, after playing around a bit I'm still struggling on how to connect my web-app to Knime.. any chance you have skype or discord so we could talk through it a bit?

Comment: Very little web-app experience, so not sure how much more help I can be - what sort of issues are you having?  If your app is writing files somewhere OK and KNIME is not picking them up very well then I might be able to make some suggestions